# upper case function C++

Tags: c++, c++11, uppercase

I am having problems with my convert String to upper case function. I have two functions right now reverse word and Upper case. reverse currently works and outputs information backwards but for some reason, uppercase wont. I have a menu which allows users to input a word then choose to either reverse or change it to uppercase

here is a snippet of code for the uppercase function.

```
string Upperword(string originalString){
    string localString;
    int len = originalString.length();

    for (int i = 0 ; i << len; i++)
        localString = toupper(originalString[i]);

    return localString;
}
```

anyone know why it wont output the word in uppercase format ?

Comment: in c++ you have the std::string library, if you are dealing with a string using this then just call the function/method ".toupper()", if its a char array then its just toupper(). (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/toupper/)

Comment: Upvoted. This is as much of a fault caused by `std::string`s enormously bloated interface, rather than anything else.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out:

```
 i << len
```

Is incorrect.  That expression will bit shift i to the left. Ultimately creating undefined behavior.  I'm certain you meant this:

```
i < len
```

This line won't likely compile:

```
localString = toupper(originalString[i]);
```

You're trying to assign a character to a string.  You want to be appending to the string.

You probably want something closer to this:

```
string Upperword(const string& originalString)
{
    string localString;
    int len = originalString.length();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < len; i++)
    {
        localString += toupper(originalString[i]);
    }
    return localString;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting aside the typo `i << len`, you continuously reassign to the returned string, character by character; the extremely bloated list of functions provided by `std::string` obviates any compiler diagnostic.

A better way is

```
#include <algorithm>
std::string Upperword(std::string originalString){
    std::string localString = std::move(originalString);
    std::transform(
        localString.begin(),
        localString.end(),
        localString.begin(), 
        [](unsigned char c){return std::toupper(c);}
    );
    return localString;
}
```

Comment: You should wrap `::toupper` in a lambda to make it more correct: `[](unsigned char c){ return std::toupper(c); }` see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper)

Comment: @Kevin: Well I'm not going to argue with that! You're hired. (And a frantic look through all my code...)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to set the size of your localString first. It is generated empty and thus setting its elements will make it crash. This can be done for example as `localString.resize(originalString.length());` before you do anything.
2. The condition should be `i<len` and preferably both len and i should be of type size_t
3. Remember that toupper depends on the current locale, do not forget to set somewhere.